# Mac Bluetooth keyboard media buttons do wrong things

Tags: mac, keyboard

I just got the aluminum apple keyboard with Bluetooth, but the media buttons don't work properly. I got it connected with my Macbook Pro, where those buttons do give the right functionality.

For example when I press F12 with the volume icon, the volume should increase, but instead it shows Spaces. I tried setting the keys in System Preferences, but I didn't find how to set, for instance, the play/pause button.

So my setup is this: Macbook Pro with monitor connected, with Bluetooth aluminum keyboard. How can I make these keys do the right things?

Comment: Since Benjamin answered your question correctly you should really click on that green checkmark to identify it as the correct answer.  thanks!

Comment: @BryanSchuetz he didn't though, I got the same issue with my bluetooth keyboard. It's not a problem with function keys at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your keyboard settings are setup wrong...

System Preferences --> Keyboard

Is "Use all F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys" checked?  If so, uncheck it.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve described problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have  a bluetooth keyboard, make sure that in the System Preferences / Ketboard set up, your bluetooth is correctly identified as  US ANSI set up. Right now, the System Prefernece panel is not even "recognizing" my keyboard, even though it's working fine. It had originally been appearing as set up for "Japan" settings, resulting in the volume controls forcing "Page" changes. Hope this is useful.